# Find object by condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following object "list":

```
{
  ...
  2: {id: 35, name: 'dog Sharik'},
  3: {id: 36, name: 'cat Murzik'}
  ...
}
```

Need to find object which consist 'cat' word in name.
What is the best way to do it (does Jquery can help with it?)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the loop and find it.Use a for loop to iterate the obj and return when the name property of the object contains the word cat.Here obj is your original object

**CODE**

```
function findmatching(obj,word){
    for(var key in obj){
      if(obj[key]['name'].indexOf(word)!=-1){
        return obj[key]
    }
   }
  }
 var mymatchingvalue=findmatching(userinput,word)
```

Comment: and who should catch that return?

Comment: if you have a word like this `dog Shacatrik` this method breaks.
I would suggest you to use a regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash/underscore.js
 _.filter(list, function(d) { return _.includes(d.name, 'cat') })